# Why does MySQL pick the wrong index in JOIN query?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, explain

I use a simple `JOIN` query, however MySQL keep showing wrong index in the `EXPLAIN` plan.

It select an index on a column that does not participate in the query.

The query is based on the primary key. I tried removing the index but then the optimizer picks another irrelevant index.

In my case table a holds ~2.5 million records and table b ~5 million records. Each record in a has ~2 records  in b.

I'm using MySql 5.6.

I did `ANALYZE` and `CHECK` on the tables.

The query takes about 70 seconds, it uses the wrong index and performs a nested loop, why?

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(SUM(a.val),0) as total
FROM a , b
where a.id = b.a_id;

1   SIMPLE  a   index   PRIMARY idx_a_c_id  5       2406691 Using index
1   SIMPLE  tv  ref idx_a_id idx_a_id   4   capb_1.a.id 1

# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'spd_transaction', 'index', 'PRIMARY', 'idx_a_c_id', '5', NULL, '2406691', 'Using index'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'tv', 'ref', 'idx_a_id', 'idx_a_id', '4', 'a.id', '1', NULL
```

Comment: hello, `a` is spd_transaction? `b` for tv?

Comment: Can you put the CREATE statement for the tables you want to JOIN? They way you write the joins is also not recommended IMHO.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date1` datetime NOT NULL,
  `c_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `acc_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `co_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_c_id` (`c_id`),
  KEY `idx_acc_id` (`acc_id`),
  KEY `fk_co_id` (`co_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `another_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `val` decimal(32,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_a_id_another_id` (`a_id`,`another_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_a_id` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `a` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: What is 'idx_a_c_id'? I could not find in table definition. Can you post `EXPLAIN` for when you are forcing primary key to be used?

Answer (score 1):

1) Looking at the nature of SQL (no predicates), i would suggest using hint (which i don't encourage often) to ignore index(s) and force DB engine to use FTS (Full Table Scan).

FTS will be better than using any index in this scenario.

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(SUM(a.val),0) as total
FROM a , b USE INDEX /* Specify no index here to ignore index and force FTS*/
where a.id = b.a_id;
```

I did not recommend to drop indexes on tables as am not aware of their in use elsewhere in ur application.

2) I would also suggest to remove JOIN on table 'B' as SQL is not making use of this costly JOIN of large table in output.

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(SUM(a.val),0) as total
FROM a USE INDEX /* Specify no index here to ignore index and force FTS*/
;
```